# Samsung Galaxy S3 keeps losing network connection and need to restart phone to reconnect

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, mobile-network

I've had my S3 for around 6 months and never had a problem. But in the last couple of days it seems to be randomly losing connection to network (T-Mobile): I have to restart my phone to reconnect. Sometimes this only lasts a few minutes before dropping out again.

Anybody else had this problem? I have no idea whats causing it. I have changed nothing on the phone, and the area I am in has good coverage.

I dont get any error msg and all seems fine -- until I try to use it to access Internet; then it tells me "no internet connection" and the internet data signal disappears. If I try to text the text just fails to send, and I cannot receive or make any calls. People who ring say it goes straight to the mailbox.

Comment: What's the symptom of it "losing connection to network"? Is there an error message? Do you just have no 'bars' of signal? The possible causes are different depending on what's going on, so please edit your question to specify it.

Comment: same thing keeps happening to me. Same phone and T-mobile. I have the icon saying I have 4g, and 4 bars of service. The only recent change is I upgraded my battery, but I didn't have a problem with that for a week. I just shrugged it off the first day because we've been having some bad weather so I figured the tower was messed up nearby. but it's been going on for a week now. No clue what the problem is. Either T-Mobile or the phone.

Comment: Have you installed custom firware? You may need to flash a new modem/basband in that case to the latest version that works in your region and with your carrier.

Answer (score 2):

your sim card needs to be cleaned, also your sim card reader should be cleaned/serviced. Your connection to phone is not completely ok just because of either your sim card is too old and have been used a lot of times in different phones, thus it needs to replaced in this case. if not, then try solution number 1.

Comment: What is solution number 1?

Comment: I can concur with this: a bad SIM can definitely lead to network drops and it can happen for no apparent reason. I have had this happen to me couple of years back.